# How to add text by clicking right on a shape in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, draw

I have a project in c# windows Forms with a draw area in which I have different shapes. I want when I click the right click on one of them to show me a menu where I can add a description. After I press enter the text to be displayed next to the shape that I selected.
Can somebody tell me?

Comment: Is this on the users end, or in design?

Comment: Can somebody tell you *what*?  Keep a list of shape objects in your code.  Text is just another one.  Draw them in the OnPaint method.  Search the one that was clicked in the OnMouseDown method.

Answer (score 0):

As you draw your shapes, use `Graphics.DrawString` to draw the text. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need the user to enter the text and when pressing Enter, the description is applied to the shape. To do this you may create a TextBox control and place it where the user right-clicked. Then you should handle OnKeyUp event of the control to detect Enter key and may be consider handling OnLeave event in case the user clicks out of the TextBox and get the value and paint it using Graphics.DrawString as @Felice said.